# Confirmation of Old Password

Tags: vb.net, passwords, change-password

I am having a problem in my condition of changing password. I want to make it simple by confirming the old password and then change the password. Here is my code

```
Private Sub btnCChangePass_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCChangePass.Click


    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\VB.net\My Projects\InventoryData.accdb"
    Dim SqlString As String = "Update Cridentials SET [Password] = @pass"
    Dim pass As String = "SELECT [Password] from Cridentials"
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
    conn.Open()

    'this part is my problem
    If (txtCOldPass.Text <> pass) Then
        MsgBox("Wrong Old Password", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Password not matched")

    ElseIf txtCOldPass.Text = Nothing And txtCNewPass.Text = Nothing And txtCConPass.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Please submit the following information", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Incomplete")

    ElseIf txtCNewPass.Text <> txtCConPass.Text Then
        MsgBox("New Password and Confirm Password in not matached", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Incomplete")

    Else

        Using con As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)

            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, con)

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtCNewPass.Text)


                con.Open()

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                con.Close()

            End Using

        End Using
        MsgBox("Changing password Success!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Successs!")
        Me.Close()
        Form1.Show()

    End If
    txtCOldPass.Focus()
    txtCOldPass.Clear()
    txtCNewPass.Clear()
    txtCConPass.Clear()

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your problem?  What isn't working?  What have you tried to fix it?  Is this something that should be on Code Review instead of Stack Overflow?

Comment: `If (txtCOldPass.Text <> pass) Then ...`? You're comparing, what, the password entered by a user with a partial query string (which misses a `WHERE` clause) . Or, do you have a single (non-hashed) password there? Anyway, that comparison doesn't make sense. Load a password from the db first, then compare it with what the user entered (you should not compare text stuff, but, all right...).